# How to make objects with names in an array?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, oop

In an array I have the symbols of the elements of the periodicity table, and I have all the attributes in another array.

I want to create an object with each symbol, with the attributes of the other array.

With this csv: https://gist.github.com/GoodmanSciences/c2dd862cd38f21b0ad36b8f96b4bf1ee#file-periodic-table-of-elements-csv

I have tried this:

```
import pandas as pd

file = '/path/to/file/PeriodicTableofElements.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)

class Elemento:
    def __init__(self, NumAtomico, Elemento, Simbolo, MassAtomica, Neutrones, Protones, Electrones, Periodo, Grupo, Fase, radioctividad, Natural, Metal, NoMetal, Metaloide, Tipo, RadioAtomico, electronegatividad, PrimeraIonizacion, densidad, Fusion, Evaporacion, CantIsotopos, Descubridor, Año, CalorEspecifico, NumOrbitas, NumVale ):
        self.NumAtomico = NumAtomico
        self.Elemento = Elemento
        self.Simbolo = Simbolo
        self.MassAtomica = MassAtomica
        self.Neutrones = Neutrones
        self.Protones = Protones
        self.Electrones = Electrones
        self.Periodo = Periodo
        self.Grupo = Grupo
        self.Fase = Fase
        self.radioctividad = radioctividad
        self.Natural = Natural
        self.Metal = Metal
        self.NoMetal = NoMetal
        self.Metaloide = Metaloide
        self.Tipo = Tipo
        self.RadioAtomico = RadioAtomico
        self.electronegatividad = electronegatividad
        self.PrimeraIonizacion = PrimeraIonizacion
        self.densidad = densidad
        self.Fusion = Fusion
        self.Evaporacion = Evaporacion
        self.CantIsotopos = CantIsotopos
        self.Descubridor = Descubridor
        self.Año = Año
        self.CalorEspecifico = CalorEspecifico
        self.NumOrbitas = NumOrbitas
        self.NumVale = NumVale
    def CrearElemento(ListaAtributos):
        return Elemento(*ListaAtributos)

simbolo = df['Symbol'].to_list()

H = Elemento.CrearElemento(df.iloc[0].to_list())
```

I am trying to make an object with the different symbols of the elements, and I want to call the objects like H.NumAtomico and the program outputs the Atomic number of the element. Thanks!!!

Comment: It's worth noting that capitalized argument names go against most Python coding style conventions. It's also worth noting that with this many arguments you probably want to make sure you can use them as named arguments.

Comment: you might be looking for a dict instead of a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An essential issue is creating names for your class instances which relate to the element symbols. See code below which resolves this issue and demonstrates using a simplified set of data to achieve what I think you want. It can be extended to your data set.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'symbol': ['H', 'He'],
                   'atomicNo': [1, 2],
                   'atomicMass': [ 1.007,4.002]})

symbols = df['symbol'].tolist()

df= df.set_index('symbol')

class Elements():
    def __init__(self,aNo,aMass):
        self.atomicNo = aNo
        self.atomicMass = aMass
        
for symbol in symbols:   #this creates a class instance for each symbol
    globals()[symbol] = Elements(df.loc[symbol, 'atomicNo'], df.loc[symbol, 'atomicMass'])
    
print(H.atomicNo)
print(He.atomicNo)
print(H.atomicMass)
print(He.atomicMass)
```

which gives:

```
1
2
1.007
4.002
```

Comment: https://github.com/BlackTlacuache/CienciaDeMateriales/ 

Thanks, all that was for this.

Comment: Please that I could help.  Buona Fortuna.